# NSMutableDictionary objects not properly accessed from methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, nslog

I've created an `NSMutableDictionary` as well as a method to add objects to the dictionary. I know that the function addObject adds objects to the dictionary properly, but later when I try to print the objects using method `Print_Object`, every single variable belonging to object prints as `null/0`. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)_stock{
    if (!_stock) {
        _stock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    }
    return _stock;  
}

-(void) addObject:(NSString*) desc key: (NSString*) theKey floatrc: (float) retailcost floatwsc: (float) wholesalecost intnoh: (int) numonhand floatns: (int) numsold {
    object_info* obj = [[object_info alloc]init];
    [obj setDescription: desc];
    [obj setRetailCost: retailcost];
    [obj setWholeSaleCost:wholesalecost];
    [obj setNumOnHand: numonhand];
    [obj setNumItemsSold: numsold];
    [self.stock setValue:obj forKey:theKey];   
}

-(void) Print_Object:(NSString *) theKey {
    object_info* obj = [self.stock objectForKey:theKey];
    NSLog(@"Key: %@ Description: %@ Retail Cost: %f Wholesale Cost: %f Number on Hand: %i Number Sold: %i", theKey, obj.description, obj.retail_cost, obj.wholesale_cost, obj.num_on_hand, obj.num_items_sold);     
}
```

This is the declaration of object_info:

```
#import "object_info.h"

@implementation object_info

//Getters
-(NSString *)description {
    return description;
}


-(float) retail_cost {
    return retail_cost;
}

-(float) wholesale_cost {
    return wholesale_cost;
}

-(int) num_on_hand {
    return num_on_hand;
}

-(int) num_items_sold {
    return num_items_sold;
}

//Setters
-(void)setDescription:(NSString *) value {
    description = value;
}

-(void) setRetailCost: (float) n {
    retail_cost = n;
}

-(void) setWholeSaleCost: (float) n {
    wholesale_cost = n;
}

-(void) setNumOnHand: (int) n {
    num_on_hand = n;
}

-(void) setNumItemsSold: (int) n {
    num_items_sold = n;
}

@end
```

This is object_info.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface object_info : NSObject
{
    NSString *description;
    float retail_cost;
    float wholesale_cost;
    int num_on_hand;
    int num_items_sold;
}

-(NSString *)description;
-(void)setDescription:(NSString *)value;

-(float) retail_cost;
-(void) setRetailCost:(float) n;

-(float) wholesale_cost;
-(void) setWholeSaleCost:(float) n;

-(int) num_on_hand;
-(void) setNumOnHand: (int) n;

-(int) num_items_sold;
-(void) setNumItemsSold:(int) n;

@end
```

Comment: In my opinion the problem is in  `[self.stock setValue:obj forKey:theKey];`. Could you try to use `setObject` instead of `setValue` because your obj is a Object? Like this
`[self.stock setObject:obj forKey:theKey];`

Comment: @nynohu that doesn't work. it's still giving me the same output. I'm currently calling the method in my main function using `[newDict Print_Object:@"Galaxy Note7"];` (using an instance of the class containing my methods) and my output is: **Key: Galaxy Note7 Description: (null) Retail Cost: 0.000000 Wholesale Cost: 0.000000 Number on Hand: 0 Number Sold: 0**

Comment: can you print obj in add object function before setting value to the dictionary

Comment: Could you provide the declaration of object_info and the caller?

Comment: @JasmeetKaur i'm required to have a separate print function as a part of my program's functionality

Comment: @user just debug it don't print just check the value of obj

Comment: @JasmeetKaur when i enter the print statement `NSLog(@"Key: %@ Description: %@ Retail Cost: %f Wholesale Cost: %f Number on Hand: %i Number Sold: %i", theKey, obj.description, obj.retail_cost, obj.wholesale_cost, obj.num_on_hand, obj.num_items_sold);` at the end of the addObject function, all of the values print correctly.

Comment: @R0CKSTAR i have updated my description.

Comment: @user6335453 object_info.h is missing

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to have them broken out as getters and setters like that?  Why not just declare them as properties?

Comment: Try to get rid of this code -(NSMutableDictionary *)_stock{
    if (!_stock) {
        _stock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    }
    return _stock; } and simply initialize the stock variable

Comment: `@interface object_info : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *descriptions;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float retailCost;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float wholeSaleCost;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int numOnHand;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int numItemsSold;

@end

@implementation object_info

@end`

Comment: If you're not having custom setters/getters, you should really just use properties and have them auto sythesized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us the declaration of `stock`? I suspect you've declared it as an `@property`, in which case your attempt to declare `-_stock` as the getter is going to be ineffective. The instance variable will be `_stock` but the getter will be just `-stock`. If this is a correct guess then were you to `NSLog(@"%@", self.stock)` you should see `(null)` as the output — your custom getter isn't called so no dictionary is ever created.

Your code generally looks very old fashioned; in particular:

1. you almost never put instance storage inside the `@interface` now; put it in the `@implementation`;
2. your entire `object_info` could be reformulated as `@property`s and then you needn't implement a thing inside that `@implementation`, just allow the properties to auto-synthesise;
3. rather than `[obj setDescription: desc];`, etc, you'd now more normally see use of dot syntax, like `obj.description = desc;`. The compiler will still ensure the proper setter (or getter) is called, it's just a formulation that requires less mental context, allowing a direct left-to-right reading;
4. the more normal modern way to access a dictionary is `dictionary[key] = value` to store and `dictionary[key]` to access.

Comment: The declaration of stock is in the main method of my program,     `NSMutableDictionary *stock = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                                  @{
        }];` I'm currently a beginner in iOS programming and I'm really trying to hone in on understanding the fundamentals, which is why my code is rather old fashioned.

Comment: That looks wrong too to be honest.  I guess it works, but...just give it @{} directly, or use new...the dictionaryWithDictionary is unnecessary.

Comment: You use `self.stock`; can you show where you declare that `stock`? No such property or getter is shown in the code you provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
  [self addObject:@"AAA" key:@"BBB" floatrc:100 floatwsc:200 intnoh:300 floatns:400];
  [self Print_Object:@"BBB"];
```

This works fine for me, do you use the wrong key?

```
  [self addObject:@"AAA" key:@"BBB" floatrc:100 floatwsc:200 intnoh:300 floatns:400];
  [self Print_Object:@"AAA"];
```

This goes wrong because the object is nil.

```
  2017-02-16 10:48:34.086 Test[53298:14250944] Key: AAA Description: (null) Retail Cost: 0.000000 Wholesale Cost: 0.000000 Number on Hand: 0 Number Sold: 0
```